# How can I get these buttons centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, responsive-design

I am working on a webiste: https://www.ffat20.nl/champions

The problem is:

How do I get those buttons centered in the page? Even if you make the page smaller it has to stay centered and responsive. Also the space between the button is not same on every button.

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:first-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

label:last-of-type {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

label:hover,
input:focus+label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked+label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box1" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box1">Fighter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box2" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box2">Assassin</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box3" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box3">Support</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box4" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box4">Marksman</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box5" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box5">Tank</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2">
      <input id="box6" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box6">Tank</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: how many times you are planning to ask this question?

Comment: till i got my answer @k185

Comment: that's not how stack works, you can not keep asking same question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make this responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393588/how-can-i-make-this-responsive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do most of what you want, remove the `translateX()` that's shifting everything to the left or right, and add `.text-center` to the col classes. But the space between buttons won't match because the space is defined by a fixed bootstrap col class and the labels are variable width. See below for another solution.

```css
.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box1" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box1">Fighter</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box2" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box2">Assassin</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box3" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box3">Support</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box4" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box4">Marksman</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box5" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box5">Tank</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <input id="box6" class="box" type="checkbox" />
      <label for="box6">Tank</label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

You could do this with bootstrap 4 out of the box because it uses flexbox, but you can easily make this use flexbox by defining a parent set to `display: flex; justify-content: center;` and, if you want to, you can re-arrange that with a media query at some point to change it to a `flex-column`.

```css
.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 62px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6a8494;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s, box-shadow .2s;
}

label::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

label:hover, input:focus + label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

input:checked + label {
  background-color: #ab576c;
}

input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .boxes {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box1" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box1">Fighter</label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box2" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box2">Assassin</label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box3" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box3">Support</label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box4" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box4">Marksman</label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box5" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box5">Tank</label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <input id="box6" class="box" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="box6">Tank</label>
  </div>
</div>
```